# Update cloned element automatically on original element update -JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lets consider below scenario:

```
 <div class="org"> <p>Some text</p> </div>
```

Now using JQuery:

```
 $vdom = $(".org").clone();
```

Now I will do some changes to my original element as

```
 $(".org p ").text("Changed text");
```

If I executes `$vdom.find('p').text()` it is still giving "Some text". How to update the cloned element automatically according to changes happened to the original element.

`$vdom.find('p').text("changed text")`, is fine for this context, but I want to automate this where every change to original element should persists in cloned element.

Is there any library to achieve this.

Comment: you could achieve this kind of thing from knockout.js, check this fiddle for an idea   [link](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/20735/)

Comment: Basically any MVC / MVVW / MVW framework. Have a look at [TodoMVC](http://todomvc.com/) for examples.

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the clonned element into the body in order to have it to the DOM stack and then it can change with a global selector like this:

```
$(".org p ").text("Changed text");
```

Run this snippet and check both texts and the console output result:

```js
var $vdom;
    $('#cloneEl').on('click', function() {
    $vdom = $(".org").clone();
    $('body').append($vdom);
});

$('#changeText').on('click', function() {
    $(".org p ").text("Changed text");
    console.log($vdom.find('p').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="cloneEl">Clone org</button>
<button id="changeText">Change org text</button>

<div class="org"> <p>Some text</p> </div>
```